# Failed to call leave inside the expressJS routing

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Currently I have an endpoint in expressJS, kicking some users out from room in socket.io

```
app.delete(
  '/projectRooms/:projectID/users/:userID',
  async (req: any, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const userID = req.params.userID;
    const socketID: string | null = await getAsync(
      `someUserKey:${userID}`
    );
    if (!socketID) {
      return next(new Error('socketID is not found'));
    }

    const socket: any = req.io.sockets.sockets.get(socketID);
    if (socket) {
      socket.leave(`project:${req.params.roomID}`);
    }

    return res.status(200).send();
  }
```

However, when the code is running on the line `leave()`, the whole request stopped and gave no response while this line works properly inside the scope of `socket.on()`.

Comment: Are you missing something or is that all there is? I don't see you ending the request anywhere with a `res.status(200).send(...)` or something similar, so it will just hang.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry, I missed that status code statement in the snippet but the program stop at `leave()` and thus I do not think that line is the main reason.

Comment: One thing you should also do is to wrap everything in a `try/catch` block to make sure it's not throwing an error, put another `res.status(400).send(...)` in the catch